# Change the color of a line built on two coordinates

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm building a line in PIL on two coordinates, for each coordinate I need to choose a random color, and I can't do it in any way

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
N = 20
x = np.linspace(1,10,N)
y = x**2
z = np.random.rand(N)
im = Image.new('L', (256, 256), 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill=0,width=2)
im.show()
# tried to change color with fill
#for i in range(len(x)-1):
   # draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill=z,width=2)
# there was such an error
# color must be int or tuple
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, it expects an integer. But in your case, the input `z` is passed which is an array of shape `(20,)`.

Since `Image` has been declared with mode `L`, it expects an 8-bit value in `fill`, i.e. a value between 0 and 255 ([Modes in PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes))

Now since you want to choose a random color, I used `np.random.randint(0,256)` to choose one between 0-255 at every iteration:

```
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill=np.random.randint(0,256),width=2)
```

**Result:**

[image]

The line drawn above is in grayscale.

**For RGB image:**

```
# set the mode to `RGB`
im2 = Image.new('RGB', (256, 256))
draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    # pass a tuple of 3 random values between 0-255
    draw2.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill=tuple(np.random.choice(range(255),size=3)),width=2)
```

**Result:**

[image]

The result is a random color line drawn between points.